# GDPR compliant captcha

Tags: captcha

Googles captcha is heavy and possibly not compliant with GDPR. I need to change.

I am looking for a GDPR compliant, light weight, captcha solution. Do you have any to recommend?

Comment: I have seen that cloudflare might have something now... just saw it when logging in to cloudflare yesterday. Did not have time to try it tho

Comment: Update: I have not used any so can't give any tips on this. I rate limited the input and made a honeypot and skipped using captacha. It seems to work fine for now

Answer (score 0):

Here are three GDPR compliant options:

- https://www.hcaptcha.com/
- https://www.mtcaptcha.com/
- https://friendlycaptcha.com/

All also offer free plans.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).